# Multiple "panes" in game window

Tags: game-maker

I would like to have multiple "panes" or sections of my game window.  Section 1 would be a view that follows the player.  I have played around with views and they, of course, are different views of the same "room".  I could use views then just cover up views 2,3 and 4 with sprites or rectangles, but it seems like there should be a more efficient way to do this.

Ideas or suggestions?

[image: Layout]

Comment: What would those "panes" do... It simply comes to that, manually overlaying the basic "view" graphics is not possible?

Comment: Well my initial plan is that pane 2 would be information on the current area, a picture and some text.  pane 3 would be chat and pane 4 would be info on who/what is in the area.  Items, monsters, pictures and text.

Answer (score 0):

If your using Game Maker: Studio

you can use the (Draw GUI) event and it will draw above everything but buttons might not with this

If your not using Game Maker: Studio

View are most likely your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, a problem we all face at some point in game development. How to make a HUD?

Here's my trick:

- Create an object, say, `obj_HUD` whose only function is to draw the HUD
- Set the depth to something like -100, so that it draws HUD **on top of** everything else
- Place one instance in the room

Let's first initialize some variables in the **create event**:

```
//CREATE EVENT
depth = -100;
width_pane2 = 150;
height_pane2 = 300;
width_pane3 = 500;
height_pane3 = 120;
width_pane4 = 120;
// Set the above values according to your needs
```

Now, for the **step event**:

```
//STEP EVENT
x = view_xview;
y = view_yview;  //Just for simplifying the code in draw event
```

Here's the code you need to add to the **draw event** of `obj_HUD`:

```
//DRAW EVENT
draw_rectangle(x , y , x+width_pane2 , y+height_pane2 , false);
draw_rectangle(x , y+view_hview-height_pane3 , x+width_pane3 , y+view_hview , false);
draw_rectangle(x+view_wview-width_pane4 , y , x+view_wview , y+view_hview , false);
```

If you need to make these transparent, set the value of alpha to something less than 1 before you draw anything, and then back to 1 after you draw everything.

```
//DRAW EVENT (TRANSPARENT HUD)    
draw_set_alpha(0.6);
draw_set_color(c_black);
draw_rectangle(x , y , x+width_pane2 , y+height_pane2 , false);
draw_rectangle(x , y+view_hview-height_pane3 , x+width_pane3 , y+view_hview , false);
draw_rectangle(x+view_wview-width_pane4 , y , x+view_wview , y+view_hview , false);
draw_set_alpha(1);
```

That should solve the problem!